# SharePoint 2013 List Item Pagination Tutorial

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I am currently working on a project which requires me to create an application page which has a custom data formatting with pagination.

Is there any reference / code samples related to paginating list items? I have tried several of them like:

1. http://sharepoint.infoyen.com/2012/03/06/sharepoint-list-pagination-using-splistitemcollectionposition/
2. http://www.refineco.com/paging-with-sharepoint-lists/
3. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/colbyafrica/2009/02/19/learning-sharepoint-part-vii-list-pagination/

but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please the below link for SharePoint JSOM list pagination. This is the best tutorial that i have came across.  -- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92

Comment: Thanks for the link, Rohit. I have not tried it yet but it looks promising, although I can't use it for my current project since there are not many developers here who are familiar with javascript. I finally ended up creating a custom pagination on C# (in my answer)

Comment: Your welcome. I have followed the same link for pagination using JSOM. And it is working perfectly for me.... :)